# Parsing or decoding .pluginPayloadAttachment files?

Tags: file, plugins, file-extensions

Messages.app now stores links in the sqlite attachment database as files with ".pluginPayloadAttachment" extension.

I have no idea how to parse these.  Running them through `xxd` reveals some indecipherable binary/hex, except for an ASCII string at the top, "ICC_PROFILE", which I assume refers to color profiling, since "RGB" appears shortly after.

Answer (score 2):

The `pluginPayloadAttachment` extension doesn't actually convey the type of the file, unfortunately. Depending on the file, you may be able to [glean the type from the byte data it begins with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). Some common types you might run into are listed here:

| Byte Array | Type |
| --- | --- |
| `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A` | PNG Image |
| `FF D8 FF` | JPEG Image |
| `47 49 46 38` | GIF Image |
| `49 49 2A 00` or `4D 4D 00 2A` | TIFF Image |